# How do I change the default Register and Login in Asp Mvc in Visual Studio to use MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

All right, I am trying to create a website login and register page. I need the website to use MySQL, and The MySQL user table only has (so far) the columns for the id, username, and password (SHA-256 hashed), and no other columns at the moment.

So what do I do, so the program will use MySQL server instead of Microsoft SQL server and can login with a Username instead of an E-mail?

I already have a MySQL connection in the Data Connection in Server Explorer, but the program will not use that database.

Comment: are you storing the connection string to the database in a web.config.. if so can you either step through the code or show the lines of code that pertain to making the database connection and the relative code that executes the query to the database..

Answer (score 0):

Ide say what you need to do is look into adding MySQL as a storage provider in EntityFramework (EF). With the new releases of EF they are looking to make it so that you don't have to use TSQL, that you can use other storage mechanisms. It looks like currently there is a driver for MySQL (have a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/)

Also you could have a look at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider but just don't use the -pre tag like they specified as it looks like the driver is no longer in pre-release.

Comment: http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/18/EntityFramework-MySql/ more examples of people using it...